# Reading array of floats from HDF5 file in Fortran

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, hdf

I can create a HDF5 file in Python using h5py, e.g.

```
    import numpy as np
    import h5py


    outfile = np.zeros((5,2))
    for i in range(5):
        outfile[i] = i


    print(outfile)
    print(outfile.dtype)

    f = h5py.File('TF.hdf5', 'w')
    dset = f.create_dataset('FT', data = outfile, dtype = 'd')
```

This prints the data, verifies that the data is type `float64`, and then saves the data to an HDF5 file, making the datatype explicit.

I can then read this HDF5 file in Fortran as,

```
    PROGRAM HDF_READER

    USE HDF5

    USE HDF5 ! This module contains all necessary modules

    IMPLICIT NONE

    CHARACTER(LEN=8), PARAMETER :: filename = "TF.hdf5" ! File name
    CHARACTER(LEN=4), PARAMETER :: dsetname = "FT"     ! Dataset name

    INTEGER(HID_T) :: file_id       ! File identifier
    INTEGER(HID_T) :: dset_id       ! Dataset identifier
    INTEGER(HID_T) :: space_id       ! Dataspace identifier
    INTEGER(HID_T) :: dtype_id       ! Dataspace identifier

    INTEGER     ::   error ! Error flag
    INTEGER     ::  i, j, cols, rows

    REAL(KIND = 8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: dset_data
    INTEGER(HSIZE_T), DIMENSION(2) :: data_dims
    INTEGER(HSIZE_T), DIMENSION(2) :: max_dims                  


    print *, 'Starting HDF5 Fortran Read'



   ! Initialize FORTRAN interface.

   CALL h5open_f(error)


   ! Open an existing file.

   CALL h5fopen_f (filename, H5F_ACC_RDWR_F, file_id, error)


   ! Open an existing dataset.

   CALL h5dopen_f(file_id, dsetname, dset_id, error)


   !Get dataspace ID
   CALL h5dget_space_f(dset_id, space_id,error)


   !Get dataspace dims

   CALL h5sget_simple_extent_dims_f(space_id,data_dims, max_dims, error)

   cols = data_dims(1)
   rows = data_dims(2)

   !Allocate dimensions to dset_data for reading
   ALLOCATE(dset_data(cols, rows))


   !Get data
   CALL h5dread_f(dset_id, H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER, dset_data, data_dims, error)



   print *, dset_data

   CALL h5close_f(error)



   END PROGRAM HDF_READER
```

However, this prints a bunch of extreme numbers, indicating that the data is not being read correctly from the HDF5 file.

**However** if I set my `dset_data` array to be of integer type, i.e. `INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: dset_data` then there is no problem, and the integer numbers print correctly.

Any ideas on how can I get this to work for double precision floats?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HDF5, the data is stored in a given datatype. When reading the data, you also specify the "in-memory" datatype explicity. HDF5 will take care of the file format that is *inside* the file and convert it (if needed) on the fly to the "in-memory" datatype that you have specified. HDF5 in Fortran is based on a C library, that ultimately needs to know this information.

You must thus specify instead of `H5T_NATIVE_INTEGER` the datatype that you have for the array. Here, `real(kind=8)` is probably `H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE` but you might as well declare your array `double precision` I would say.

You see proper data for integer because you store round floats in the file. Else the result would be rounded upon reading.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Out of interest, do you know of an HDF resource for Fortran?

Comment: I could point to specific libraries, such as a generic one by Thomas Robitaille https://github.com/astrofrog/fortranlib/blob/master/src/lib_hdf5.f90 and one by me that is focused on appending molecular trajectories https://github.com/pdebuyl/fortran_h5md They can give you an idea of "how to use" HDF5 with Fortran. Else, I use the official HDF5 reference extensively

Comment: Better than double precison in modern Fortran would be to use h5kind_to_type to get the mapping of a kind of a datatype to a HDF5 handle. And DON'T USE EXPLICIT KINDS. Kind=8 for reals is not portable and I can show you examples where it breaks. Use selected_real_kind or the constants in the iso_fortran_env intrinsic module

Comment: Thanks both for your help